# Alternative proof that probability of empty space is 0

Tags: probability-theory, monoid

In my book, and everywhere the writter found in internet, to prove that $P(\emptyset)=0$, they do this:

$1=P(Ω)=P(Ω∪∅)=P(Ω)+P(∅) \implies P(∅)=0$ because $Ω∩∅=∅.$

When the writter tried to prove this, she did it differently:

Since $\emptyset \square \emptyset = \emptyset$ (for $\square = \cap, \cup$), we have $P(\emptyset) = P(\emptyset \cup \emptyset) = P(\emptyset)+P(\emptyset)$ and therefore since $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ is a cancellative monoid, it follows that $P(\emptyset) = 0$.

Is this correct? If yes why is the usual proof the former? My proof seems more general as it does not make use of the axiom $P(\Omega) = 1$.

Comment: of course, both are correct.

Comment: I suppose these are subtly different, but I don't see anything deep here. What would be the meaning of a probability space if it didn't have finite measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that your proof works for any measure space,  unnecessarily as it’s an axiom that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, while the quoted proof works in *finite* measure spaces. It is slightly more general, yes, but the quoted proofs are in the context of probability spaces so that they only care about finite measure spaces anyway.

Comment: In an arbitrary measure space without the axiom $P(\emptyset) = 0$, my proof is actually not enough since it could be feasible that $P(\emptyset) = +\infty$. Maybe this is why the usual proof uses a set with finite measure.

Comment: i edited my comment to account for that

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion than both proofs need a finite measure, so there is no increased generality.

Comment: Yes exactly, this should answer why there's no advantage to my proof over the usual one.